# How to fit a GEE model in r for multiple categories of independent and response variable? More than 3 categories

Tags: r

I'm trying to fit GEE model in `R` i.e:

```
fit1 <-geeglm (crime~month+date+time,data=data,family =gaussian,=subject,corstr="ind")
Fit2 <-update(fit1,corstr ="exch")
Fit3<-update(fit1,corstr="ar1")
QIC(fit1,Fit2,Fit3)
```

I'm not getting an error,however, I observe no difference in QIC output. What could be the problem?
The variable crime has 9 levels,  month has 12 levels, date has 31 levels and time has 24 levels

Comment: Sorry, should I repost the question with what in have done in r?

Comment: It would be better to have an example that is reproducible as others can test it and check the underlying issue.